# Why does the compiler claim CGRect has no width member?

Tags: ios, swift

Note that I'm not trying to set the value in a CGRect. I'm mystified as to why the compiler is issuing this claim:

```
let widthFactor = 0.8
let oldWidth = wholeFrameView.frame.width
let newWidth = wholeFrameView.frame.width * widthFactor // Value of type '(CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'width'
let newWidth2 = wholeFrameView.frame.width * 0.8  // This is fine.
```

Comment: Width is a CGFloat where your multiplier is a Double. Explicitly declare the type of your multiplier.

Comment: Thanks. Any guess as to why that error message appears to be totally wrong?

Comment: Actually the error message is quite fascinating. It is not saying that `frame` has no `width`. It is saying that some _function_ (taking a CGRect and returning a CGRect) has no `width`. But I cannot imagine what function it is talking about! I've reported this to the bug site.

Comment: CGRect actually does have getter and setter methods for this value; but of course  it does not take or return a CGRect.

Comment: Yes, there IS a reason to be mystified by an error message that states something demonstrably wrong.

Comment: @matt See my answer for the method. It's from `UIView`.

Answer (score 3):

Width is a `CGFloat` where your multiplier is a `Double`. Explicitly declare the type of your multiplier:

```
let widthFactor: CGFloat = 0.8
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the type issue. The question is why the compiler is making this erroneous claim about the width member.

Comment: The compiler is making its best guess based on the information it has.

Answer (score 2):

All the dimensions of a `CGRect` are of type `CGFloat`, not `Double`, and because Swift is especially strict about types, you can't multiply a `CGFloat` by a `Double`.

The interesting thing though, is that both `CGFloat` and `Double` implement `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`. This means that `0.8`, a "float literal", can be interpreted as either a `Double` or a `CGFloat`. Without context, it's always a `Double`, because of how the compiler is designed. Note that this only applies to float literals like 3.14, 3e8 etc, and not to identifiers of variables.

So the expression `wholeFrameView.frame.width * 0.8` is valid because the compiler sees that `width` is a `CGFloat`, so it treats `0.8` as a `CGFloat` as well. No problems.

On the other hand, when you declare the variable `widthFactor`, it is automatically given the type `Double`, because there aren't any more context on that line to suggest to the compiler that you want it to be any other type.

This can be fixed by directly telling the compiler that you want `widthFactor` to be a `CGFloat`:

```
let widthFactor: CGFloat = 0.8
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the type issue. The question is why the compiler is making this erroneous claim about the width member.

Comment: @Oscar Oh wait! I didn't realise how weird the error message was. Well, when I tried some similar code, I got the message "binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'Double'", so I can't reproduce your problem. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sweeper Weird, I was able to reproduce that error message just by putting the code in the question into a bare view controller's `viewDidLoad` and changing `wholeFrameView` to just `view`.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler I now can reproduce it too. I was doing it in a playground, and `wholeFrameView` is a global variable. Maybe that's why.

Comment: Ahh, yeah could be. In any case, this seems like a bug. I believe @matt 's already reported it.

Comment: @Oscar See the previous discussion. Apparently, if you do it in `viewDidLoad` in a playground, then you get "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context". So a bug it is then...

Comment: Thanks guys. I've reported it to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as others have noted, you can't multiply a `Double` and a `CGFloat`, the compiler doesn't know what you're intending.

So, instead of giving you an error about  the [frame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame) property, which you currently think it's doing, it's actually making its best guess*, and giving you an error related to the [frame *method*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622603-frame). *No method* method has a `width` property, so what it tells you is true.

*Of course, its best guess is not good enough, hence a human being coming here to ask a question about it. So please [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa)!

> **Stepping onto my soapbox:** This confusion would be avoided if Apple hadn't named the method the thing it returns. The convention to prefix all such methods with `get` solves the problem. *Some* convention is important in any language with first-class functions, to disambiguate between properties and methods.

Comment: No, I don’t believe that. That method has a labeled parameter `forAlignmentRect`. There’s no way the compiler would see it here.

Comment: `let frame: (CGRect) -> CGRect = UIView().frame`

Comment: The confusion with the error message getting confused within `frame` is interesting, but not the real issue. (And editorials about well established Swift naming conventions aren’t really relevant/useful.) If you try this with `bounds`, which doesn’t have this overload, I don’t think the error message is much better, “Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context”. Either way, we really should get a message like “Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'Double'”, which is what you usually get when you try to multiple `CGFloat` and `Double`.

Comment: Bug filed! Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

`wholeFrameView.frame` has no member `width`.  Also, you need `widthFactor` to be of type `CGFloat`.  Try:

```
let newWidth = wholeFrameView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(widthFactor)
```

Comment: "`wholeFrameView.frame` has no member `width`" `CGRect`s _do_ in fact have a [width](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454758-width) member.

Comment: yes, @TylerTheCompiler , but it seems like the width property of `size` is what he's looking for.  The compiler error is from the mismatched types.

Comment: The width of the rectangle _is_ the width of `size`. It's the same thing. The only difference is that `CGRect.width` will always be positive, regardless of whether its `size.width` is positive or negative.